# google analytics Tracking code not firing

Tags: google-analytics

I have this tracking code, I am not sure what else I can do to it to make it fire. When the page loads nothing happens, no errors, I just don't see the data being sent to google.

```
<script>
  if (hotelname == " foohotels")
  {

    document.write(<img height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" src="https://www.googlefoo.com/xxxx/clk/pagead/conversion/xxxx/?label=HPA&guid=ON&script=0&ord=$$random$$&data=xxx_partner_hotel_id%3Dhotel-name%3Bhct_base_price%3Dtotal%3Bhct_total_price%3Dtotal2%3Bhct_currency_code%3Dcurrency%3Bhct_checkin_date%3Darrival%3Bhct_length_of_stay%3Dnights%3Bhct_date_format%3D%Y-%m-%d%3Bhct_booking_xref%3Dbooking%3Bhct_ver%3D1.0.i"/>);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: by leaving the 4 spaces to create the code it was bringing the whole paragraph down and not leaving spaces

Comment: Is this even google analytics code?

Comment: As @Tushar has pointed out, your code does not seem to be a Google Analytics code. Nevertheless, you are missing quotes from document.write command, and this will throw an error. Try document.write('<img ... />'); instead.

Comment: it's googletraveladsservices.com  conversion code

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Syntax: `document.write()` expects a string, something between single or double quotes (good thing that the string can contain the other type). As your thing contains double quotes already, I suggest surrounding it with single quotes:
  `document.write('<img height="1"...');`
- What it does: `document.write()` overwrites the document, see this example:

```js
function test(){
  document.write("I am brand new content, everything else is gone.");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Clicky</button>
```

So it is not sure that such change (having a proper string) will cover everything you need, you might better use `document.createElement("img")`, set its attributes, and put it somewhere in the existing document.